# Scraping and crawling Quora using Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I saw this thread here,
[Crawl Quora Q&As using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63250752/crawl-quora-qas-using-beautifulsoup)

And got introduced to Selenium...

I learnt how to install it from here,
https://gist.github.com/korakot/5c8e21a5af63966d80a676af0ce15067

Since I want scrape a Quora webpage, I coded on colab...

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# open it, go to a website, and get results
wd = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

import time

URL = "https://www.quora.com/What-was-your-prom-like"
#URL = "https://www.quora.com/profile/%E0%AE%AA%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%B2%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%9C%E0%AE%BF-%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%B8%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%A8%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%A9%E0%AF%8D-Balaji-Viswanathan"

wd.get(URL)
PAUSE_TIME = 2

lh = wd.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:

    wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(PAUSE_TIME)
    nh = wd.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if nh == lh:
        break
    lh = nh
spans = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.q-box.qu-userSelect--text')
for span in spans:
    print(span.text)
    print('-' * 70 + '\n')
```

The output looks like this:

> ```
> What was your prom like?
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Prom. That experience of mythical proportions, whipped up into a foam
> and placed on a pedestal. “Oh, you simply must go! You’ll regret it
> when you’re older…” I didn’t want to go. I was adamant! And yet, on
> prom night, I found myself stuffed into a suit (for the last time, I
> promised myself) and sitting at a table. It started okay; I found some
> friends and we talked and walked around. One of my friends had a good
> laugh when I couldn’t find my table. The food wasn’t amazing, best
> described as downright bland, but I always expect food at parties to
> be lacklustre at best. Continue Reading
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Are you expected to have sex with your prom date after the prom?
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Did you have sex after prom?
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> My daughter has been crying because no one asked her to the prom. What
> should I do?
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> What is prom like?
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> What did you wear to your prom?
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> My Prom was tonight Continue Reading
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> I ended up with three dates by mistake… whoops Names have been omitted
> to protect the innocent Senior year, I asked out a very dear friend of
> mine to prom. She told me maybe which later turned into a no. She
> decided she was going with her friend from her band class. Continue
> Reading
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> My date's existence offended the sensibilities of a drunk guy. My
> date, who I'll call Nancy, had graduated from high school. We had been
> dating for months, so I invited her to my senior prom. Nancy was
> reluctant to go. She felt like she would be conspicuous and out of
> place. I convinced her, though. It was important to me. So we went.
> We'd been there maybe ten minutes when a drunk student yelled at
> Nancy. “Are you a dyke?” His speech was loud, belligerent, and
> slurred. Then, he turned and left. Thinking that I should talk to him,
> I called for him to wait. Wiser than me, Nancy pulled me back. “We sh
> Continue Reading
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> What do people usually do after prom?
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> What do teenagers usually do after prom?
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Does college have a prom?
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> What age should a teen be able to come home from prom?
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> What is a high school prom like?
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> My best friend decided that we were all going to the prom. "We" being
> the collection of druggies, artists and outcasts that comprised the
> ragged clique that clung together likes ants crossing a river during
> the hell that was high school. Grace was a bit different. She was a
> proud, stoned outcast and valedictorian. She vexed authority and we
> loved her for it. If she said prom, we said sure. We asked why. she
> said, " Its ironic don't you see? We'll take acid and the very act of
> tripping will stand as protest to this ridiculous rite of passage that
> is America's paltry offering to its disenfranchise Continue Reading
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> I hated my prom. I had gone because my parents guilted me into it. “I
> always wanted to go but was too poor. I wish I had the chance.” -Mom
> So I went. I don't even like dresses. I prefer my usual shorts/jeans
> and a tank top. I don't wear much make up. My sister slathered me in
> it. I don't have a dancing bone in my body. I felt uncomfortable being
> dragged to dance. Continue Reading
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> The problem with the British version of a prom is, it's shit! Granted
> I can only talk for my own school and my own prom, but I'm almost
> certain it's the same right across the U.K. There's no real build up,
> hardly any money is spent, there's no committee organising it, there's
> no pomp or pizazz, it's no right of passage as it is in the US and A.
> Those that want to lose their virginity already have. Nobody is saving
> themselves for prom night. You're either one of the "cool people" that
> have already "done it" or you're one of the other kinds of people that
> haven't "done it", and feel like you'll ne Continue Reading
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Prom Sonnet My parents said I had to go to prom. A venture I knew
> would end badly. I said alright but I had my qualms. But I still
> bought a suit that was classy. I paid a couple hundred for both
> tickets. When the day came I went to go get her. Her friend was there
> trying to solicit. Just like that I felt like a chauffeur. We arrive
> at prom and she didn’t want to dance. I had no problem so we stuck to
> talking. I went to the bathroom and she saw her chance. I returned to
> see her and the quarterback grinding. I said nothing, but there was
> anger in my eyes. I was a fool not to see through her guise.
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Uh. We had “most likely” awards. You know which one. It was at
> Ritz-Carlton so I was confused why the food was just okay (actually I
> think the desserts were pretty good.) Some people slow danced. We had
> an after-party rave. It was alright, not too bad. At least I got to
> hang out with my friends.
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Nothing dramatic, unless you count me eating my dinner in a rush and
> almost throwing up in the bathroom. Oh, and the guy that I like was
> eyeing me from across the room. But past that, it was a very fun night
> for my best friends and me. We danced our butts off, to say the least.
> Everyone was dancing (some more inappropriate than others), the
> teachers joined in, and no one was fighting. Before prom, my friends
> and I took pictures to commemorate the occasion. There were a few wild
> after parties, but I didn’t go. Instead, I went to Whataburger with my
> best friend before heading home. Just a regular ni Continue Reading
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> I don’t know; I wasn’t there. Yes, I made it through the entire four
> years of high school without attending a single adolescent mating
> ritual (also known as a school dance), and I didn’t come away as a
> social pariah (at least not for that). The thought of hanging out with
> a bunch of my peers who were overly-concerned about getting drunk
> and/or getting laid didn’t appeal to me in the least. I was too busy
> geeking out about Gene Puerling ’s use of vocal harmony, or the latest
> Manhattan Transfer project. These interests still intrigue me 35 years
> later, but I couldn’t tell you who went with whom to Continue Reading
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

1. The first issue is that the code is working of the Quora Question
   webpage but not for the second link (I commented it),
   https://www.quora.com/profile/%E0%AE%AA%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%B2%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%9C%E0%AE%BF-%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%B8%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%A8%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%A9%E0%AF%8D-Balaji-Viswanathan .
   It is the link to the Quora profile of the most popular Quoran. The
   code just keeps on running endlessly and does not move forward
   past the `time.sleep(PAUSE_TIME)` statement. I want to modify the
   code so that it can read questions, and the answers below them, from
   profiles as well answers on question pages.
2. The second issue is that the output results in just the truncated
   answers. How do I get the text such that it expands each answer on
   the given link, https://www.quora.com/What-was-your-prom-like, after
   clicking on `Continue reading`, or on `More` on profile links like
   these,
   https://www.quora.com/profile/Sean-Kernan.
3. I would like to list all links/ hyperlinks on these two webpages. What should I write to get/ print all the in-site links within the two webpages, starting with `https://www.quora.com/`. I don't know if there is a way to do that using selenium. Or Beautiful soup.
   Getting all links in `href` by `soup.findAll("a")` isn't working.
4. The last question is just my curiosity, is there a way that while
   harvesting the site through scraping, I get myself logged in into my
   Quora account through code and then proceed with scraping? If so,
   how can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer question 3, because I've done something similar in my web scraper

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
links = []
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if(link['href'].startswith("https://")):
        links.append(link['href'])
```

I'm using requests, so I'm not sure how it would work with your code, but if you have some sort of usage of BeautifulSoup you should be able to use some parts of my code.

Comment: Hi. Thanks you so much. It helps. I used set instead to avoid repetitions. But this gives me all the links within any url, while I only require the 'internal' ones, which have the same domain name, i.e. `https://www.quora.com/`.  Also how can I extract the domain name of a given `url`, say https://www.quora.com/profile/Sean-Kernan, through code, instead of writing it manually?

Comment: If you only want the internal ones, most likely you will want a `not` before the `link['href'].startswith("https://")`, because internal ones will likely just be `/something`.
To extract the domain, what I did was `link.split("/")[2]`